# Как упростить хендлер?

Tags: python, telegram-bot, handlers

Как можно упростить данный хендлей, просто если очень писать много городов то выйдет код в много строчек.
P.s в дальнейшем хочу сделать, чтобы вариант который выбрал пользователь записывался в БД, и потом информацию которую он хочет получить, он получал бы только для своего города

```
@dp.inline_handler()
async def empty_query(query: types.InlineQuery):
    await query.answer(results=[
        types.InlineQueryResultArticle(
            id='1',
            title='Москва',
            description='Описание',
            input_message_content=types.InputTextMessageContent(
                message_text='Москва')
        ),
        types.InlineQueryResultArticle(
            id='2',
            title='СПб',
            description='Описание',
            input_message_content=types.InputTextMessageContent(
                message_text='СПб')
        ),
        types.InlineQueryResultArticle(
            id='3',
            title='Воронеж',
            description='Описание',
            input_message_content=types.InputTextMessageContent(
                message_text='Воронеж')
        )

    ])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Данные передавать в отдельной переменной data, остальной код получится фиксированной длины:

```
    data = [['1', 'Москва', 'Описание', 'Москва'], ['2', 'СПб', 'Описание', 'СПб'], ]

    r = [types.InlineQueryResultArticle(
        id=d[0], title=d[1], description=d[2], 
        input_message_content=types.InputTextMessageContent(message_text=d[3])
    ) for d in data]
    await query.answer(results=r)
```